# Error while try to bind an object to a template with ngModel?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

This should be an easy thing, but I cant figure out what goes wrong.

I have this in my class:

```
interface Message {
  type:  string;
  email: string;
}

export class MyClass {
  public message: Message;
  public email: string;

  constructor() { }

  // ...
}
```

If I bind the email variable it just works (`[(ngModel)]='email'`) but if I try to bind the message `[(ngModel)]='message.email'` I got an error: `Cannot read property 'email' of undefined.` Why cant angular reach my object variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `message` property to be able to bind an input on one of its properties:

```
export class MyClass {
  public message: Message = { type: '...', email: '...'};
  public email: string;

  constructor() { }

  // ...
}
```

**Edit**

In your case, `Message` is an interface so you can't use it to instantiate an object of this type. You need to use the literal object expression to instantiate an object of type `Message`. TypeScript will check that the literal object has all required elements.

If you want to instantiate the type, you need to create a class. Interfaces have no correspondance in the compiled code, classes have.

Here is a sample:

```
export class Message {
  constructor(public type: string, public email: string) {
  }
}

export class MyClass {
  public message: Message = new Message('type', 'email');
  public email: string;

  constructor() { }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: That wont compile. `Message` doesn't exist. Ofc I can use `public message: Message = { 'type': '', 'email': ''};` but that just looks bad. I thought typescript handle this for me.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that `Message` was an interface. Using the literal expression to instantiate an object of type `Message` is possible. TypeScript will check that the literal object has all required elements. If you want to instantiate the type, you need to create a class... Interfaces have no correspondance in the compiled code, classes have.

Comment: That was what felt like a little over engineering to me. Seems there is no other way then. If u edit your answer to have the class method too then I will accept the answer when I can.